# Adding values to the end of a row if data meets criteria with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am needing to get all values in one row if the meet a criteria.

[image: Dataframe]

To look like this:

[image: Final Dataframe]

Tried:

```
for c in df['Account Number']:
    for i in final['Account']:
        if c == i:
            x = x + 1
            service_date = 'Service Date ' + str(x)
            final[service_date] = df['DOS']
```

Result:
[Result of Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MssGU.png)

Comment: Post data in text format, not as screenshots. See [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_table`:

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index=['Patient Name', 'Account-Number'],
                      columns=df.groupby('Account-Number').cumcount().add(1).astype(str),
                      values=['DOS', 'Procedure', 'Location'], aggfunc='first')
         .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)).reset_index()

out.columns = [ '_'.join([v, n]) if n else v for v, n in out.columns]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Patient Name  Account-Number DOS_1 Location_1  Procedure_1 DOS_2 Location_2  Procedure_2 DOS_3 Location_3  Procedure_3
0         Alex               3   dc1       EAST          6.0   NaN        NaN          NaN   NaN        NaN          NaN
1        Louis               1   da1       EAST          1.0   da2      NORTH          2.0   da3       WEST          3.0
2         Paul               2   db1      SOUTH          4.0   db2      NORTH          5.0   NaN        NaN          NaN
```

Input:

```
>>> df
  Patient Name  Account-Number  DOS  Procedure Location
0        Louis               1  da1          1     EAST
1        Louis               1  da2          2    NORTH
2        Louis               1  da3          3     WEST
3         Paul               2  db1          4    SOUTH
4         Paul               2  db2          5    NORTH
5         Alex               3  dc1          6     EAST
```